# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor Add an Arbitrary URL

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape

How do I add a url to SgmlLinkExtractor?  That is, how do I add an arbitrary url to run the callback on?

To elaborate, using dirbot as an example: https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot/blob/master/dirbot/spiders/googledir.py

**parse_category** only accesses everything that matches the SgmlLinkExtractor SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='directory.google.com/[A-Z][a-zA-Z_/]+$')

Answer (score 0):

Use BaseSpider instead of CrawlSpider, then set add to start_requests or start_urls []

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "myspider"

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request("https://www.example.com",
            callback=self.parse)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

class ThemenHubSpider(CrawlSpider):

```
name = 'themenHub'
allowed_domains = ['themen.t-online.de']
start_urls = ["http://themen.t-online.de/themen-a-z/a"]
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['id_\d+']), 'parse_news')]
```